# Android Emulator Auto Accept Welcome Prompts

Tags: android, automation, android-emulator, startup, android-virtual-device

I am setting up a CI server which creates Android AVDs on the fly to run automated UI tests. This works great, but since the CI gets brand new emulators with brand new images each time a job is run, I get all of the Android welcome and first run and do you agree prompts. These break my tests.

Is there anyway to have the emulator auto-accept or dismiss all of these prompts?

---

Here are some examples:

[image: Chrome welcome prompt]

[image: Keyboard welcome prompt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging and experimentation, I've figured out a way to work around both of the prompts mentioned above. There isn't a catch-all solution, but here it goes, piece by piece.

## Chrome

Before starting up Chrome for the first time, run this command with adb:

```
./adb shell 'echo "chrome --disable-fre --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'
```

Basically, this writes out a file to a known location which Chrome will check on boot. All of the flags specified in the command are obeyed, and those inheriently disable all of the first run prompts. [This link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/luT20jYLRbE/S8xPeEVVAwAJ) was very helpful.

## Keyboard (Gboard)

The Android shell has a tool called `ime` to manage the input methods available on the device. By default, on newer devices in English, the input method is LatinIME. This is the Latin implementation of Gboard, which provided the legal prompt shown above.

The easiest solution is to select another keyboard which doesn't have this prompt. I used the old SoftKeyboard:

```
./adb shell 'ime set com.example.android.softkeyboard/.SoftKeyboard'
```

You may obtain a list of available keyboards, like so:

```
./adb shell 'ime list -a -s'
```

## Final Result

[image: Final result of settings changes]

Comment: By now, 2023, this method seems to be outdated